# How to integrate paypal to my web application

Tags: java, paypal

Since 2 days i was looking for good tutorials about how to test paypal via my web application (java/j2ee). I followed this tutorial [paypal integration tutorial](http://ask2mujahed.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/java-paypal-integration-tutorial-1/)
I have followed all the steps without any issue. I've created a "BUY" button that redirects to the page paypal.jsp ( as it shown in the tutorial with the adequate username, passwor and signature). But when i click on the button Buy i get an erro page 
[image]

**Snapshot in english**
[image: Paypal error]

Comment: I need to know the steps i am missing

Comment: Would you please give a screenshot in English?